# search results to a variable in search.php

Tags: search

Is there any way I can get the search results to a variable in search.php file? Now I have the following code in my search.php file.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <h3 class="pagetitle"><?php _e( 'Search Results', 'buddypress' ) ?></h3>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        ......
```

I know the while loop uses some variable that contains the search results. Now I want to use this variable before the loop. I need this variable to do some processing before displaying the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $search_query = get_search_query(); ?>
```

I think you're searching for this function: [`get_search_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_query)

Comment: get_search_query returns the search criteria, not the results. I am looking to retrieve search results in my search.jsp.

Comment: global $posts; print_r($posts); You mean this?

Comment: That seems to be close. But it has only 10 records in it. What if I need to get all the search results?

Comment: Don't no for sure, but you can try: global $wp_query; print_r($wp_query);

Comment: Hmm I think that's not it, you can get all the results by making a custom query with your search var and posts_per_page at -1 (infinite).